# webpack devserver proxy not work

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I have problem with my local devserver.

In my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apimapyloader"></script>
```

In webpack config:

```
proxy: {

            "/apimapyloader": {
                target: "http://api.mapy.cz/loader.js",
                pathRewrite: { "^/apimapyloader": "" },
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            },....
```

But proxy didn't work at all. In network manager I see everything ok, but content of "/apimapyloader" is index.html again

Comment: ok, my bad... path to file (loader.js) must be in pathRewrite